# CefSharp html loaded exceeds 2097152 characters

Tags: html, winforms, cefsharp

I am using CefSharp in winform to show an html page, where I have some data to pass and show. here is the code:

```
private CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser1;

string html = Utils.GetEmbeddedResource(htmlFilePath);
html = html.Replace("/*NODES*/", nodesJson);

BrowserSettings settings = new BrowserSettings {
    DefaultEncoding = "utf-8"
};
chromiumWebBrowser1.BrowserSettings = settings;
chromiumWebBrowser1.LoadHtml(html, base64Encode: true);
```

When it tried to load the html, an error occurred:

```
[0901/180248.815:WARNING:navigation_controller_impl.cc(283)] Refusing to load URL as it exceeds 2097152 characters.
```

I printed the length of html, which is 2250120. How to handle long html data? Please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When no `Url` is provided then a [Data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) is used. This has a hard limit on the size of a Data URI.

If you provide a `Url` as the second param then a different under then a [ResourceHandler](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#resourcehandler) is used to load your URL.

**Example**

```cs
chromiumWebBrowser1.LoadHtml(html, "http://myapp.test/index.html");
```

https://cefsharp.github.io/api/113.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_LoadHtml_2.htm